# While playing youtube video, there are two vertical black bars to left and right. How to remove this bars?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have viewing problem in YouTubePlayerView. It is not displaying fullscreen horizontally. There are two vertical black bars to left and right side. You can see in the attached Image. How can I remove these bars?

```
    <com.ecomapps.tubeplay.widget.AspectRatioView
        android:id="@+id/ignored_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:aspectRatio="1.90">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    </com.ecomapps.tubeplay.widget.AspectRatioView>
```

[image: This is my image and you can see the black vertical bars to left and right side. How can I remove this?]

Answer (score 0):

remove com.ecomapps.tubeplay.widget.AspectRatioView

Comment: You set  app:aspectRatio="1.90", so view adopted to this aspect ratio and added black bars. 

How should look video if aspect ratio of video and aspect ratio of screen different?

Answer (score 0):

It works when I declare

```
layout_height="wrap_content".

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Try this.